# Can old film lenses like Tamron be used with modern DSLRs?

Tags: canon, lens-mount, canon-600d, lens-adapter, tamron

I have a Canon EOS 600D Digital SLR and would like to use an old Tamron 70-210mm lens for a film Contax camera on the new camera. Is this possible with an adapter?

Answer (score 2):

I am a Contax lenses user (on Olympus 4/3). Once you get the adapter ring, the usual way is to set the DSLR in aperture priority, step down the lens, focus and shoot.

I have also tested my lenses on Canon. This is totally doable, however note that metering in Canon can be affected by the way you open your lens and may need a light compensation which depend of the lens and the opening. For studio this is not a problem, for field pictures this may require a little bit of training.

Note also that I don't know the Tamron 70-210, I can't grant you it worth the pain...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to use them completely manually as the Contax lens requires.

What you need is a [mount adapter like this one](http://www.amazon.ca/Fotodiox-Adapter-Contax-Yashica-Digital/dp/B001G4SHT0).

Answer (score 0):

Canon is a good camera for vintage lenses. you can use C/y, Pentax K, and M42. The trick is to go for the vintage primes. The zoom offerings were pretty bad. Might be so bad that your kit lens is better. But the right vintage primes are very nice and give a great atmosphere to the imsge. You can read about them [HERE](http://www.pentaxforums.com/lensreviews/)